# собственная шифровка, неправильный выход из программы без ошибки

Tags: python

пытаюсь создать свою шифровку, но python завершает прогу без ошибок, но неправильно. вот код:

```
lis = [
    'q', 'w', 'e', 'r', 't', 'y', 'u', 'i', 'o', 'p', 'a', 's', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'z', 'x', 'c', 'v',
    'b', 'n', 'm'
]

i = input('введите текст (латиница): ')
if i in lis:
    i = i.replace('q', '1')
    i = i.replace('w', '2')
    i = i.replace('e', '3')
    i = i.replace('r', '4')
    i = i.replace('t', '5')
    i = i.replace('y', '6')
    i = i.replace('u', '7')
    i = i.replace('i', '8')
    i = i.replace('o', '9')
    i = i.replace('p', '10')
    print(i)
```

(код не дописан)

вот, что выдаёт:

```
введите текст (латиница): qwerty

Process finished with exit code 0
```

вот, что должен выдавать:

```
введите текст (латиница): qwerty
123456

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: `if i in lis` — на таком примере это условие никогда не выполнится

Comment: @andreymal ай блин, там даже if... я как for прочитал :D

Comment: введи одну букву, тогда будет работать

Answer (score 2):

Это ответ не про ошибки, а про то, что подобную операцию проще сделать так, используя translate, чем писать тридцать раз replace

```
l = list(enumerate(lis))
d = {ord(x): str(i) for i, x in enumerate(lis, start=1)}
i = input('введите текст (латини)ца): ')
print(i.translate(d))  # 123456 для qwerty
```

Answer (score -1):

Во-первых, вы сравниваете **строку** с массивом **символов**.

Во-вторых, вы делаете это ровно один раз, после чего ваша программа завершается, чтобы сравнить строку посимвольно нужно использовать цикл `for`.

Должно быть как-то вот так:

```python
for letter in i:
   if letter in lis:
      \\тут код замены
```